# why base64 string breaks when trying to pass it using javascript xmlhttprequest object?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, base64

I am trying to pass base64 string which is quite a large one using javascript xmlhttprequest and on debug, I am able to encode correctly         but somehow when it reaches server some parts of it for example "+" character was found missing.Many times I also get a 500 internal server error. other times, it is breaking on the server side. Here is my code:

```
    function markAttendanceSuccess(fingerPacket,id,senderId,fromDate,toDate,leave)
    {
        var xhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("POST","myUrl",true);

    xhttp.onload=function()
    {
        if(this.status===200)
            {               
                var response=this.responseText;
                let index=response.indexOf(">")+1;
                response=response.substring(index,response.length);
                index=response.indexOf(">")+1;
                let index2=response.lastIndexOf("<");
                response=response.substring(index,index2).toLowerCase();
                if(response==="attendance marked successfully")
                {
                    alert("success");
                }           
                else
                {
                    alert(response);
                }


            }
        else {
            alert(this.statusText);
        }

    }
    xhttp.onerror=function()
    {
        alert(this.responseText);
    }
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    let loginModel=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("loginModel"));
    let str="";

    str=fingerPacket+"~"+senderId+"~1~1~01-jan-1900~01-jan-1900~0";

    }



    str=btoa(str);

    xhttp.send("parameter="+str);
    }
```

Comment: try `str=encodeURIComponent(btoa(str))` - `+`, `/` and `=` are not "url safe"

Comment: trying now telling u the result

Comment: Doesnt work. I am getting internal server-500 error.

Comment: well, what is server coded in, can you show the code that tries to decode the base64 (perhaps it needs to decode the `%2B`, `%2F`, `%3D` characters it is receiving now

Comment: server is using c#. Its an asp.net web service.